# Как назвать самца мыши?

Tags: род, морфология

У оленя есть оленихи есть олень, у медведицы — медведь, у волчицы — волк, у суки — кобель, а кто есть у мыши?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самец мыши. У мелких животных как правило, половые особенности в названии не проявляются, максимум разговорные варианты (ср. *крот, крыса, хомяк*). Шутливо-разговорным вариантом для обозначения мышинного самца будет слово **мыш**. Оно даже в литературных источниках встречается, у Леонида Филатова:

> Кто ему на дно ковша бросил дохлого мыша́?

Но в литературном языке этого слова нет.

Comment: Слышала еще просторечное "мышак"

Comment: А помните в "Хрониках Нарнии" был Мыш? Именно так, без мягкого знака

Comment: "Хроники Нарнии" не читал, поэтому помнить их не могу. Насколько слышал, написаны они на английском, где определить пол у животного можно только по его поведению, следовательно "Мыш" это уже попытка омужествления сдова переводчиком. Из забавных прижившихся ошибок переводчиков, можно вспомнить о том, что пантера Багира в произведении Киплинга - это представиьель мужского пола.

Comment: Вообще-то тут дело не в мелкости животного, а в значимости пола для хозяйственной или еще какой деятельности. Антропогенный подход, так сказать. У косули тоже нет специального названия самца.. Да и вообще они с трудом образуются у животных с общим названием ж.р.: россомаха, пума, дрофа, обезьяна вообще и мартышка, горилла - в частности. Про рыбу (акула, щука, селедка) даже не говорю.

Answer (score 2):

Мышь так и будет (самка и самец)

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о мышах, как о представителях данного вида животных, то употребляется слово "мышь", только. А, если речь идет о конкретных, определенных, существах, тогда, конечно, мыш. Например, поймал огромного мышА. Это как с лисицей. Если о виде, то лисицы, а о конкретном существе - лис.

Answer (score 0):

Мыш - разговорный вариант для "мыши" вообще, вне зависимости от пола. Норматьивность весьма слабая.

"Багира" - думаю, это вполне осознная ошибка. Просто иначе возникают сложности восприятия русскоязычным читателем. Тем более - ребенком. 
Лермотнов вон из любви сосны к пальме вообще дружбу сделал. Гейне тихо крил в сторонке. А тут "какой-то" Киплинг...

Comment: А в чём сложность назвать Багиром, а пантеру перевести леопардом (это одно и тоже, только окрас разный)? А по поводу восприятия, лично у меня поведение Багиры в главе "Весенний гон" вызывало недоумение, уж как-то чрезмерно открыто она проявляла своё либидо перед представителем другого пола. Если же знать, что перед нами большой кот, а не кошка, то всё встаёт на свои места.

Comment: У "больших кошек" не как у маленьких. Про пантер не в курсе, но львицы и тигрицы ативнее своих самцов.

Comment: А при чём тут активность, если автор произведения подразумевал другие социо-культурные отношения? В главе "Весенний гон" Багира прихорашивается, чтобы найти партнёра для спаривания, причём ни о каком материнстве тут речи не идёт. Это подходящая модель для подражания девушки? В Викторианскую эпоху, когда жил Киплинг, приличная девушка так себя вести не могла.

Comment: Господь с Вами, какой-такой пример для подражения в сказке про выкормленного волками индийского ребенка *Викторианской эпохи*? Запад есть Запад, Восток есть Восток... 

К тому же, мы, вроде, про перевод?! Или Вы в английском тексте ощибку обнаружили?

Comment: Да сколько угодно там примеров для подражания, смелость, смекалка, дружба, отвага и многое другое. Но вы так и не ответили какие сложности восприятия появились бы у русскоязычного читателя, если бы пантера Багира была леопардом Багиром, как это подразумевалось у Киплинга?

Answer (score -1):

Конечно самец мыши это Мышак. Во многих русских сказках упоминается это имя существительное.
 "Шли по лесочку кот с кошкой да мышь с мышаком"
"И поскакали мыши да мышаки из-под Емелиной печи"
Мышь,как и любое другое млекопитающее имеет слово, характерное для мужского рода. 
Мышак-самец мыши, исп для изменения сущ. по родам (словарь Ожегова м т.3 с.251)

Comment: Приведете хоть один пример того, что упоминается, да еще "конечно"?