# Употребляется ли слово "мышь" в мужском роде?

Tags: грамматика

По тексту подразумевается мышь самец. Как правильно написать "пробежал мышь", с мягким знаком или нет?

Comment: Если вам дан ответ, который помог, отметьте его __галочкой__.

Comment: Похожий вопрос уже был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/25607/Как-назвать-самца-мыши. Как назвать самца мыши?

Comment: ***МЫШ** разг. шутл., комп. жарг. — мышь (во всех значениях, особенно если надо подчеркнуть, что это самец мыши) ◆ Представляешь, вчера в офисе мыша́ поймали. ◆ Кто ему на дно ковша бросил дохлого мыша́? Л. А. Филатов, «Про Федота-стрельца, удалого молодца» ◆ Мыш у нас пока только один — это Джерри.*

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете это слово в мужском роде, следует писать его без мягкого знака на конце: *мыш*.

Дело в том, что в орфографическом правиле сказано: мягкий знак пишется после шипящих на конце слов **третьего** склонения. К третьему же склонению относятся только существительные женского рода. Переводя *мышь* в мужской род, вы меняете и склонение этого слова, а значит, и орфографию.

Comment: Нужно поправить: не только женского рода. Тюль ведь тоже третьего склонения.

Comment: @Третийглаз тюль второго склонения (в литературном языке). Любуемся тюлем, а не тюлью.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать